# aliasing template to template argument

Tags: templates, range, alias, d

This code is from the source code of Phobos.

```
// This template simply aliases itself to R and is useful for consistency in
// generic code.
template Take(R)
if (isInputRange!(Unqual!R) &&
((!isInfinite!(Unqual!R) && hasSlicing!(Unqual!R)) || is(R T == Take!T)))
{
    alias Take = R;
}
```

But what does it mean / what does it do / when is it useful?

Answer (score 1):

After constraint checking, the template is effectively an identity function; that is, `is(Take!MyRange == MyRange)` is true.

The constraints check if R is an input range, and if it either is infinite and has slicing, or is already a `Take` range.